# Gulp plug-in to replace variables with meta values

Tags: gulp, marketo

I'm building email templates for Marketo's email 2.0 application. These templates take advantage of a variable declarations.
These are referenced as meta values which are then be editable by when generating emails based of a template. Variable meta references include; strings, boolean, colors, numbers etc.

The syntax to declare a variable follows:

```
<meta class="mktoNumber" id="articleSectionSpacerBottom" mktoname="Article heading spacer bottom" default="30" min="0" max="30" step="5">
```

The variable is called in the body of a document like this:

```
${articleSpacerBottom}
```

I'd like to find a plugin that can process the default values for each variable so I can locally test email templates.

So for each variable or each instance of variable, find the associated meta tag and get the default value.

I'm hoping to add this to a html processing task so it runs immediately after the `injectsPartials` plug-in.

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
  gulp.src(source + '*.+(html|php)')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.injectPartials({
        removeTags: true
    }))
    .pipe($.inline({
        base: source,
        css: $.cleanCss,
        disabledTypes: ['svg', 'img']
    }))
    .pipe($.inlineCss({
        applyStyleTags: true,
        applyLinkTags: true,
        removeStyleTags: false,
        removeLinkTags: true,
        applyWidthAttributes: true,
        applyTableAttributes: true
    })) 
    .pipe($.replace('src="images/', 'src="' + mtkosrc + template +'-'))
    .pipe($.replace('mktoname', 'mktoName'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(build))
    .pipe(reload({
        stream: true
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there's any out-of-the-box plugins that do what you want. You'll have to write something yourself.

This shouldn't be too hard however. You can use [`map-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-stream) to gain access to each [`vinyl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl) file object in the stream. Then use [`cheerio`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to parse the HTML and find the `<meta>` tags. After that its a simple search & replace operation.

Here's a small example that works for me:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var map = require('map-stream');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(map(function(file, done) {
      var html = file.contents.toString();
      var $$ = cheerio.load(html);
      $$('meta').each(function() {
        var meta = $$(this);
        var variable = new RegExp('\\$\\{' + meta.attr('id') + '\\}', 'g');
        html = html.replace(variable, meta.attr('default'));
      });
      file.contents = new Buffer(html);
      done(null, file);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta class="mktoNumber" id="articleSectionSpacerBottom1" mktoname="Article heading spacer bottom" default="30" min="0" max="30" step="5">
<meta class="mktoNumber" id="articleSectionSpacerBottom2" mktoname="Article heading spacer bottom" default="42" min="0" max="30" step="5">
</head>
<body>
${articleSectionSpacerBottom1}
${articleSectionSpacerBottom2}
</body>
</html>
```

**build/index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta class="mktoNumber" id="articleSectionSpacerBottom1" mktoname="Article heading spacer bottom" default="30" min="0" max="30" step="5">
<meta class="mktoNumber" id="articleSectionSpacerBottom2" mktoname="Article heading spacer bottom" default="42" min="0" max="30" step="5">
</head>
<body>
30
42
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I had no idea where to start. It works like a charm.